# Find integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation but I can't really find an integrating factor:
$$\underbrace{y\cdot(1+x)}_{P}\:dx+\underbrace{x\cdot(1+y)}_{Q}\:dy=0$$
I know I must find $\mu \equiv \mu (x, y)$ so that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu P)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu Q)$$
Therefore:
$$P\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}+\mu \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=Q\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} + \mu \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$
I have trouble working out the partials of $\mu$. I have tried doing $\mu\equiv \mu (\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon \equiv \epsilon (x, y)$, therefore:
$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \epsilon} \cdot \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial y}$$
And the same for the $x$. But I don't know where to go from here. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu P)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu Q)$$
$$\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial y}( P)+P\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu )=\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x}( Q)+Q\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu )$$
Consider $\mu=h(xy)$
 We have that:
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial xy} \cdot \frac{\partial xy}{\partial y}=x\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial xy}}$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial xy} \cdot \frac{\partial xy}{\partial x}=y\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial xy}}$$
$$\mu\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}+xP\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial xy}=\mu\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}+yQ\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial yx}$$
$$(xP-yQ)\frac{d\mu}{d xy} =\mu(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})$$
It's separable.
$$xy(x-y)\frac{d \mu}{d xy}=\mu (y-x)$$
$$\dfrac {d \mu}{\mu}=-\dfrac {dxy}{xy}$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {\mu =\dfrac 1 {xy}}$$

Comment: How did you come up with the idea that the integrating factor should depend on the product of (xy)? (I'm just asking for future problems I might encounter)

Comment: For this type of DE $yfdx+xgdy=0$ it depends on $xy$  @fdez